# Set UILabel opaque on transparent UIView

Tags: swift, opacity

I have view with `layer.opacity = 0.84`

This view contains a few `UILabel`. And these labels a bit transparent. My question is: how i can make opaque UILabel's and half-transparent UIView?

What i try to do:

- `lbl.layer.opacity = 1`
- add to view with `layer.opacity = 0.84` a new one with `backgroundColor = .clear` and attach my labels to the second view (with clear background)

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok guys, i found solution

the logic

- make main view `backgroundColor = .clear`
- add a *new view* to main. But do not use **constraints**, use frame
- in a *new view* set `.alpha = 0.84`
- attach labels to **main** view, not *new view*

  example

  `// self its main view` 
  `self.backgroundColor = .clear` 
  `let blurView = BlurViewMaker.createBlurView(with: self.bounds)` 
  `blurView.alpha = 0.84` 
  `self.addSubview(blurView)` 

  `self.addSubview(lblEventName)` 
  `self.addSubview(lblEventDate)` 
  `self.addSubview(lblEventTag)` 
  `// do constraints from labels to self`

Comment: Yup, that should work too, although Apple says to not use alpha values other than 1.0 on blur views, I have had it work. (Thanks for circling back and self-answering. That's really helpful for others who have the same question. Voted.)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply an opacity to a layer (or a view) all sublayers are affected, and will be at least that transparent. If sublayers are also < 100% opaque, the transparency will be cumulative.

Instead, I would set your base layer's `isOpaque` property to false and fill it with partly transparent gray, leave the layer's opacity at 1.0, and then add one or more fully opaque sublayers containing your text content.